Calculating the shortest path connecting multiple points (like TSP) on road network in QGIS
I have a set of points representing kiosks and a road network layer in QGIS. I need to calculate the shortest route that connects all kiosks using the road network, starting from one point and visiting each kiosk in an optimal order (similar to solving a Traveling Salesman Problem).
I've tried using the QNEAT3 plugin to generate an OD matrix for pairwise shortest paths between kiosks, but I'm unsure how to proceed with finding the optimal route through all kiosks. I’ve considered using Python and NetworkX, but I'm not certain how to integrate the OD matrix or if there’s a better approach directly in QGIS.
Has anyone tackled something similar in QGIS, and can you suggest the best workflow or any specific tools/plugins that might help?

Doesn't pgrouting do TSP?

If you have GRASS installed you can use v.net.salesman:

Creates a cycle connecting given nodes (Traveling salesman problem).


